# formatting a Linear Program in LyX

Tags: lyx

I am trying to achieve the following with LyX. How can I do it?

[image: an LP example. from Approximation Algorithms , Vazirani]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which code do you use?

Comment: Have you tried Insert > Math > AMS align?

Comment: thank you, AMS align solved it. now i have to remember that this is the solution for the next time :)

Comment: @LyXuser yes, it takes time to remember these things. If you have a recent LyX version, and you are in math mode, ctrl+return should put you into an AMS align also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Insert > Math > AMS align.